# Opens DB & works fine on hoster, but on localhost: "Could not find stored procedure xyz"

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I need to make some changes to an existing app that is running fine on my hoster. I download the database and can open it in Visual Studio for development and testing, but my localhost will not let me use the stored procedures that are there: "Could not find stored procedure xyz". I have made no changes yet, I want to make sure I have a fully functional environment before I start doing things.

The stored procedures are there -- I can see and use them all in SSMS.

I think I have permissions set correctly via SSMS, but I don't do this very often can easily have missed something somewhere. What do I do now? My connection strings for local vs hoster are identical, except of the server name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the login for the DB is finding the correct database?  Each login has a default database that it will look in for executing queries when the objects are not fully qualified.  So if you are calling ProcName or dbo.ProcName in MyDatabase but the login has a default database of "master" then you can get that error.  Either fully qualify the objects (not a bad idea anyway) or update the settings for the login to have the correct default database.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the login is finding the right db. I do several things with it before calling the stored procedure. Still, I'm going to give you suggestions some thought and see what happens.

Comment: As an experiment for permissions, you can GRANT EXECUTE ON proc TO PUBLIC to see if that helps. And what "things" are you doing in the DB before calling the Proc?

Comment: It now looks like my problem was in VS. It needed to know the connection parameters. Thank you so much for your efforts.